# How to get adjacent cell of matched element in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets

I have two columns (`A` and `B`) in a Google spreadsheet:

```
   A              B
Number      Description
   2            desc1
   5            desc2
   1            desc3
   3            desc4
```

How can I return the content of cell `B` that's next to the minimum number in column `A`?

(In this case it's `desc3` since `1` is the minimum number in `A`.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is not very accurate example, but it should give you your result and workability.

```
=indirect("B"&ArrayFormula(sum((row(A2:A5)*(A2:A5=MIN(A2:A5))))))
```

**Explanation:**
We will use **=indirect**  approach formula.

--- **"B"**   by this we will define what column will be returned
--- **&**  this is delimiter that will connect "B" letter of searched column with following returned number of **"row"**

then goes the **ArrayFormula** function

--- **row(A2:A5)*(A2:A5=MIN(A2:A5)** is the range of rows that will be searched for **MIN(A2:A5)** criteria to return us the needed **"row"**.

Thus we have connected **"B"** + **"3"** and got **=B3**  cell value.

Comment: Works. But I replaced **"B"** with `REGEXEXTRACT(ADDRESS(ROW(), COLUMN()), "[A-Z]+")` to make it more general like mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22129496/900394

Comment: glad to help, your note will be also a help to me ;)

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
=index(B:B,match(min(A:A,A:A),A:A,0))
```

[INDEX](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098242)
[MATCH](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093378)
[MIN](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094017)